# Determine the exponential functions equation given the formula $y=Ca^x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

Determine the exponential functions equation given the formula $y=C a^x$.

[image]

My calculation: $42= 250a^4$ to

$a^4= \frac{42}{250}$ and then how can I get rid of $a^4$?

I know I can square root it out two times. I can apparently also make it to the power of $\frac{1}{4}$. But how does that work? I don't understand that part.

Answer (score 2):

You need to solve for $a$ to get the exponential function.
Since $ a^4 = \frac{42}{250} = \frac{21}{125} $
So, take the fourth root on both sides: $$a=\sqrt[4]{\frac{21}{125}}$$So your equation is$$250\left(\sqrt[4]{\frac{21}{125}}\right)^x$$Edit: The reason why we take the fourth root of both sides is because it is the inverse function of the fourth power, so they cancel out.
In general: $$a^n=b\implies a=b^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Comment: Pardon me, where did you get 12/125 from?

Comment: @Ibti 24/250 and 12/125 are the same (just the factor of 2 being cancelled from both numerator and denominator)

Comment: @mrtechtroid But it's not 24, it's 42/250.